# How do i find the ssh access of my linux machine?

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm pretty new to coding and software development so this might sound like a stupid question, but I already have a linux machine and I want to connect to that linux machine from another machine, but to do that I need the SSH address to do that. My question is how do I find the ssh address of my linux machine so I can connect to it via a different machine?

Comment: It's one of those questions where I have so little info about your situation that I don't know where to start asking… How did you acquire the Linux machine?

Comment: The SSH address is the network address. You can use the IP address or the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

To connect using the Internet Protocol (IP), used for web browsing, email and other purposes, such as Secure Shell (SSH), one needs to know the [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) and [IP port](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/tcpip-port). By convention, [Port 22 is used for SSH](https://monovm.com/blog/what-is-ssh-port/), though that is not fixed in stone.

For example, if a web browser such as Edge or Firefox is connected to Google.com by HTTPS, it looked up the IP address on a DNS server such as Cloudflare, and got the IPv6 address of `2607:f8b0:4006:823::200e` for Google.com. The [convention for HTTPS is to use Port 443](https://thecyphere.com/blog/https-port-443/), so the full address, with port included, is `2607:f8b0:4006:823::200e:443`.

You will need to find the IPv4 or (IPv6) address of the other machine, and to connect to that address on Port 22. If you are on a home network, many routers connect each machine using an IP address assigned for a duration. Your machine might use [192.168.0.2](https://www.lifewire.com/192-168-0-1-818066), and another in your local area network (LAN) might be assigned 192.168.0.5. In many Linux distros, type [`ip addr show`](https://itsfoss.com/check-ip-address-ubuntu/) in terminal to find that machines address... or use the abbrev. `ip a`.

Answer (score 0):

On the "maschine" (that's a "host") open a shell and issue

```
sudo ss -tuanop | grep sshd
```

It will ask you your login password, as it requires the root rights to read the details of the deamon processes.

If you get an "command not found"-error, use the command

```
sudo netstat -tuanop | grep sshd
```

You will (hopefully) get something like

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      56723/sshd: /usr/sb  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::22                :::*                    LISTEN      56723/sshd: /usr/sb  off (0.00/0/0)
```

This tells you:

- sshd is running and serving.
- the port used is `22`
- the host has IPv4 und IPv6 addresses available.

*If empty, the ssh-server deamon is not active. — Then solve that problem first.*

Issue the command

```
ip --brief addr
```

This will show you the currently used IP adresses of the host:

```
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
enp4s0           UP             192.168.188.15/24 2001:db7b::10/64 
wlp3s0           DOWN
```

- The IPv4 address is `192.168.188.15`
- The IPv6 address is `2001:db7b::10`

Issue the command

```
hostname
```

The output is the (network) name of your linux comuter. If everything is configured propperly in your network you can address your computer by this name. Else you've to use the IP-address.
Here the output is

```
linuxmachine
```

Your username you should know. Else issue

```
whoami
```

to get your username.

Knowing these details, you can try to connect from a computer in your network:

Using the samples above you can connect with ssh by one of these commands:

```sh
# As the port 22 is default you can use the simplest command:
ssh username@linuxmachine

#To tell explicitely the port
ssh -p22 username@linuxmachine

#If "linuxmachine is not found, use an IP-address:
ssh -p22 username@192.167.188.15

#or by IPv6 address:
ssh -p22 username@fe80::978b:e12:c126:15ca
´´´
```